# When trying to use Model.create({}) I get this: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Right now I'm having some trouble trying to post data with Model.create. I'll show the archives first.

**Some words are in portuguese

usuarios migration:

```
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('usuarios', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    nome: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    login: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    senha_hash: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    created_at: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    updated_at: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
  }),

  down: (queryInterface) => queryInterface.dropTable('usuarios'),
};
```

Model file -> Usuario.js

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs';

export default class Aluno extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      nome: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: '',
        validate: {
          len: {
            args: [3, 255],
            msg: 'O nome deve conter de 3 a 255 caracteres.',
          },
        },
      },
      login: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: '',
        unique: {
          msg: 'Este nome de usuário já existe.',
        },
      },
      senha_hash: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: '',
      },
      senha: {
        type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
        defaultValue: '',
        validate: {
          len: {
            args: [6, 24],
            msg: 'A senha precisa ter entre 6 e 24.',
          },
        },
      },
    }, {
      sequelize,
    });

    this.addHook('beforeSave', (user) => {
      user.senha_hash = bcryptjs.hash(user.senha, 8);
    });

    return this;
  }
}
```

UsuarioController.js

```
import Usuario from '../models/Usuario';

class UsuarioController {
  async index(req, res) {
    const usuarios = await Usuario.findAll();

    return res.status(200).json(usuarios);
  }

  async store(req, res) {
    try {
      const { nome, login, senha } = req.body;

      const dados = { nome, login, senha };

      const novoUsuario = await Usuario.create(dados);

      // if (dados === null || dados === undefined) {
      //   return res.status(400).json('Dados vazios');
      // }
      return res.status(200).json(novoUsuario);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

export default new UsuarioController();
```

usuarioRoutes.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import usuarioController from '../controllers/UsuarioController';

const router = new Router();

router.post('/', usuarioController.store);
router.get('/', usuarioController.index);

export default router;
```

app.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

import './src/database';
import express from 'express';
import homeRoutes from './src/routes/homeRoutes';
import alunoRoutes from './src/routes/alunoRoutes';
import instituicaoRoutes from './src/routes/instituicaoRoutes';
import disciplinaRoutes from './src/routes/disciplinaRoutes';
import turmaRoutes from './src/routes/turmaRoutes';
import usuarioRoutes from './src/routes/usuarioRoutes';

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    this.app.use(express.json());
  }

  routes() {
    this.app.use('/', homeRoutes);
    this.app.use('/alunos', alunoRoutes);
    this.app.use('/instituicao', instituicaoRoutes);
    this.app.use('/disciplina', disciplinaRoutes);
    this.app.use('/turma', turmaRoutes);
    this.app.use('/usuarios', usuarioRoutes);
  }
}

export default new App().app;
```

All the other models and controllers have functional post and get routes, except for this one. I pass all the informations the model needs (nome, login, senha). 'senha_hash' is made automatically with the hash of the field 'senha'. I tested this to see if the object was really null or undefined:

```
      const { nome, login, senha } = req.body;

      const dados = { nome, login, senha };

      const novoUsuario = await Usuario.create(dados);

      if (dados === null || dados === undefined) {
        return res.status(400).json('Dados vazios');
      }
      return res.status(200).json(novoUsuario);
```

I put the three fields from the req.body in a single const and made a condition where if this const had a null or undefined value, it would send "Dados vaiozs"(translating: empy data), or else it would just return the values of the object. It doesn't show the message 'empty data', it just shows the error this question is about. Does someone know what could this be?

Comment: `dados` can never be null or undefined. You assigned an object to it 2 lines earlier.

Comment: Maybe `nome`, `login`, or `senha` is undefined. What does `console.log(dados)` show?

Comment: Console.log(dados) and res.json(dados) shows the exact data I sent in req.body: {"nome":"ExampleName", "login":"ExampleLogin", "senha": ExamplePassword}

Comment: @Khiuta Does the error happen if you comment out `this.addHook` in your model?

Comment: @RobinThomas well this is kinda going to take a while because I was doing that at school and I won't have access to it until next monday (i couldn't upload it to github). But I have the same code here at home and it just works!! It is *exactly* the same code because I got it from an online class.

Comment: @Khiuta How are you calling `Usuario.init()`?

Comment: @RobinThomas you mean in the Usuario.js file?
static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
        code
    }, {
     sequelize
   }
  return this;

The same way both at home and school

Comment: Yes, where is that `init()` function called from? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: Oh, it comes from Model. I import { Model } from sequelize and I access it's function "init()" using super.